# Doctrine gather multiple rows on a multipurpose table (unidirectional without join table ManyToMany?)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Well, I'm on a rigid table in Doctrine as this:

- TextsRepo (language_id, **text_id**, text)
- SuchTable1 (such_id, **title_text_id**, **another_text_id**)
- SuchTable2 (such_id, **header_text_id**, **meta_text_id**)
- ...

Data example:

- TextRepo -> `(1, 1, "Lorem"), (2, 1, "Ipsum"), (3, 1, "Dolor"), (1, 2, "Sit"), (1, 3, "Amet"), (1, 4, "Consecteur"), etc..`
- SuchTable1 -> `(100, 1, 2), (102, 3, 4), (103, 4, 5), etc.`
- SuchTable1 -> `(101, 6, 7), (102, 8, 9), (103, 10, 11), etc.`

And I need to recover all the rows from a text_id (in all languages_id), like in DQL:

`SELECT s, n FROM AppBundle:SuchTable1 s, JOIN **s.titles** WHERE s.such_id=100`

And receive: `{such_id => 100, title_text_id => 1, another_text_id => 2,  titles => [{1, 1, "Lorem"}, {2, 1, "Ipsum"}, {3, 1, "Dolor"}]`

One of the main problems I see is that obviously I can't put **title_text_id**, **another_text_id** as PK (for e.g.).

The question with this scenario is, is it possible to recover those rows with a mapping association? Not using third Join Tables as I can't alter the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can map it so :
(if you want to use the inverse side keep the '%optional: ... %' annotations content, else remove it.)

```
class SuchTable1
{
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TextIds"%optional: , inversedBy="suchTable1EntitiesWithThisAsTitle"%)
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="title_text_id")
    */
    private $title;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TextIds"%optional: , inversedBy="suchTable1EntitiesWithThisAsAnother")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="another_text_id")
    */
    private $anotherText;
}

class SuchTable2
{
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TextIds"%optional: , inversedBy="suchTable2EntitiesWithThisAsHeader")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="header_text_id")
    */
    private $header;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TextIds"%optional: , inversedBy="suchTable2EntitiesWithThisAsMeta")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="meta_text_id")
    */
    private $meta;
}

class TextRepo
{
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Languages"%optional: , inversedBy="texts")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="language_id")
    */
    private $language

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TextIds"%optional: , inversedBy="tranlastions")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="text_id")
    */
    private $textId;

    private $text;
}

class TextIds
{
    /**
    * Optional :
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TextRepo",mappedBy="textId")
    */
    private $translations;

    /**
    * Optional :
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\SuchTable1",mappedBy="title")
    */
    private $suchTable1EntitiesWithThisAsTitle;

    /**
    * Optional :
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\SuchTable1",mappedBy="anotherText")
    */
    private $suchTable1EntitiesWithThisAsAnother;

    /**
    * Optional :
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\SuchTable1",mappedBy="header")
    */
    private $suchTable2EntitiesWithThisAsHeader;

    /**
    * Optional :
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\SuchTable1",mappedBy="meta")
    */
    private $suchTable2EntitiesWithThisAsMeta;
}
```